# Set up default value of the the parameter of the element from the tuple argument

Tags: scala, function, default

```
def found( names(String, String) ): Unit {
  // Do something
}
```

The parameter list of the function found is a string tuple (string, string)

How to set up the default value of the second tuple element as the first one like `names(String, String=names._1)` Or does this even allowed? if so how can I passing the argument? `found( ("FirstName", ???) )` or `found("FirstName")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a tuple `(String, String)` then you have both strings. If you have not both strings then this is not a tuple. The whole parameter can have default value, part of a tuple can't. If default value uses other parameter then parameters should be in different parameter lists.

Try

```
def found(name1: String)(name2: String = name1): Unit = ???

found("FirstName")()
found("FirstName")("LastName")

def foundTuple(names: (String, String)): Unit = found(names._1)(names._2)

foundTuple(("FirstName", "LastName"))
foundTuple("FirstName", "LastName")
```